# Creating folder in VSO via VSO API

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have been trying to figure out how is possible to create a query folder via VSO api, but I always the "Method not allowed" message.

I'm using **Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client** package to connect VSO. [This](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) page says that this library is needed for me. I can query data, but it seems something is missing to create data. This library is fit for me because I have a WebApi whihch manages the communication to VSO API.

Here is my code:

```c#
public QueryHierarchyItem CreateFolderAsync(string folderName)
        {

            QueryHierarchyItem newFolder = new QueryHierarchyItem()
            {
                Name = folderName,
                IsFolder = true,
                //Path = "Queries/Shared Queries/" + folderName,
                IsPublic = true
            };

            QueryHierarchyItem item = witClient.CreateQueryAsync(newFolder, _projectName, null).Result;

            return item;

        }
```

I have tried to play with the Path property but it did not help.

- I have checked the user rights. My user is member of "Project Administrators", and
- rights are also set up to manage query folders (Click the chevron next to the "Shared Queries" folder -> select "Security") as group and as single user. It did not help.

I use a free account. The strange is that I have logged in with the same user from Visual Studio and I can manage the folders. Is this functionality available for free accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this blog from MSDN for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/06/16/work-item-tracking-queries-object-model-in-2010.aspx

Quote the code here:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace QueryAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Project myproject = null;
        public static QueryFolder GetMyQueriesFolder()
        {
            foreach (QueryFolder folder in myproject.QueryHierarchy)
            {
                if (folder.IsPersonal == true)
                    return folder;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot find the My Queries folder");
        }

        public static QueryFolder AddNewFolder(string folderName)
        {
            QueryFolder folder = new QueryFolder(folderName, GetMyQueriesFolder());
            myproject.QueryHierarchy.Save();
            return folder;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("Your TFS Server URI"));
            WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore(coll);
            myproject = store.Projects["Your project name"];
            QueryFolder myNewfolder = AddNewFolder("Your folder name");
        }
    }
}
```